# SocketException permission denied when trying to bind port 80 or 443 to Kestrel in Azure Container Instance with .NET 8

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-container-instances

This issue happens with Linux Azure Container Instances (ACI) after upgrading the app to .NET 8; the exact same code works targeting .NET 6 (i.e. if I only change `<TargetFramework>` in the `.csproj` and the publish profile).

I get the following exception when launching an ASP.NET Core 8 app in an ACI:

```
fail: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[11]
      Hosting failed to start
      System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (13): Permission denied
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportOptions.CreateDefaultBoundListenSocket(EndPoint endpoint)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportFactory.BindAsync(EndPoint endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.TransportManager.BindAsync(EndPoint endPoint, ConnectionDelegate connectionDelegate, EndpointConfig endpointConfig, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass28_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.ListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.AnyIPListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.EndpointsStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(ListenOptions[] listenOptions, AddressBindContext context, Func`2 useHttps, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>b__15_1(IHostedService service, CancellationToken token)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.ForeachService[T](IEnumerable`1 services, CancellationToken token, Boolean concurrent, Boolean abortOnFirstException, List`1 exceptions, Func`3 operation)
Unhandled exception. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (13): Permission denied
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportOptions.CreateDefaultBoundListenSocket(EndPoint endpoint)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportFactory.BindAsync(EndPoint endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.TransportManager.BindAsync(EndPoint endPoint, ConnectionDelegate connectionDelegate, EndpointConfig endpointConfig, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass28_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.ListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.AnyIPListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.EndpointsStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(ListenOptions[] listenOptions, AddressBindContext context, Func`2 useHttps, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>b__15_1(IHostedService service, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.ForeachService[T](IEnumerable`1 services, CancellationToken token, Boolean concurrent, Boolean abortOnFirstException, List`1 exceptions, Func`3 operation)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in E:\MyProject.Web\Program.cs:line 42
```

This happens if I try to make Kestrel listen on ports 80, 443, or both. I don't get any more information with `Trace`-level logging.

This is what I tried:

- Alternative configuration options for Kestrel, but it doesn't matter how I configure this, be it in `appsettings.json` under `Kestrel__Endpoints`, the `ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS` and `ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS` environment variables, or with `UseKestrel()`.
- Making Kestrel listen under the internal IP of the container, not any IP, but that yields the same result.
- Using different ports, like 8080 and 8443. That does work, but since I need this web app to be available under standard HTTP and HTTPS, 80 and 443 should be the ones publicly exposed. And I can't do that while using a different port internally, since [ACI doesn't support port mapping](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/8bc62918-0d25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0858).
- I'm aware of [the default port having changed from 80 to 8080](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/containers/8.0/aspnet-port) with .NET 8, however, that should be addressed by setting the port to 80 explicitly as under the first point, nor should it affect port 443.
- ACI [seems to reserve port 443](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-faq#does-the-aci-service-reserve-ports-for-service-functionality-) but neither should that affect port 80, nor should port 443 work with .NET 6. So, this is a .NET-related issue, not this port reservation.
- Using [`--privileged` with `az container create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-create) (as well as `--allow-escalation`) but nothing changed.

I can't reproduce this locally under Windows.

The container image is published self-contained.

Can somebody help me understand what I may be doing wrong? Is this perhaps an undocumented breaking change, in .NET 8 or how ACI supports .NET 8?

Cross-post from [an `aspnetcore` discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/discussions/53015) since nobody replied there for a week.

Update: I cross-posted to [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1483906/running-net-8-azure-container-instance-app-as-root) for visibility.

Update 2: I dug some more and found that actually this might be the breaking change relevant to this issue, not the default port change: [New non-root 'app' user in Linux images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/containers/8.0/app-user). Also see [the blogpost it links](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/securing-containers-with-rootless/). And sure enough, with .NET 6 the container's user is `root`, and with .NET 8 it's `app`.

I tried

```
az container create `
    --run-as-group 0 `
    --run-as-user 0 `
...
```

to run the container as root but it still runs as `app`. Adding `USER root` in the Dockerfile doesn't do anything either because the Dockerfile has no effect for Azure Container Instance, they use [`az container create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-create) as a substitute. I also tried setting [`ContainerUser`](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk-container-builds/blob/main/docs/ContainerCustomization.md#containeruser) with `<ContainerUser>root</ContainerUser>` but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. It was actually setting [ContainerUser](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk-container-builds/blob/main/docs/ContainerCustomization.md#containeruser) with `<ContainerUser>root</ContainerUser>` in the csproj. No other changes necessary.

So, all in all, compared to the .NET 6 version, my app has the following changes to target .NET 8:

- `<TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>` in the csproj.
- `<TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>` in the pubxml used by `az container create`.
- `<ContainerUser>root</ContainerUser>` in the csproj, see below the context.

Full section of the csproj:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>MyId</UserSecretsId>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <NoDefaultLaunchSettingsFile>true</NoDefaultLaunchSettingsFile>
    <EnableSdkContainerSupport>true</EnableSdkContainerSupport>
    <ContainerUser>root</ContainerUser>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I did try this before, but apparently, I messed up something during publishing, but now it's clear.

I also opened an issue to clarify this in the docs: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/39082.

Answer (score 1):

.NET 8 linux containers are not running under user "root" anymore. And because port 80 is a [Privileged port](https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html), you can not make Kestrel listen on port 80.

I'm not familiar with Container Instances, but I think you can do port mapping as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/quickstart-docker-cli). You can leave the default 8080 port for inside the container.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Docker Compose ACI integration that you linked to is not available anymore: https://docs.docker.com/cloud/. It most possibly wouldn't have worked anyway, since as linked in my question, ACI doesn't support port mapping. I do need port 80 and 443 open though, since this is a web app. I can't put a reverse proxy in front of it since this app actually serves as a reverse proxy. I updated the question with what else I tried.