# How to get Azure Container Apps to accept the new .NET 8 default http port 8080?

Tags: .net-8.0, azure-container-apps

.NET 8 changed the default port inside docker containers from 80 to 8080. But the Azure Container Apps expect the application to listen on port 80 inside the container.

I can't change the default port to port 80 inside docker. If i try that, then I get a Socket exception exception "Permission Denied" like described here: [socketexception-permission-denied-when-trying-to-bind-port-80-or-443-to-kestrel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77753907/socketexception-permission-denied-when-trying-to-bind-port-80-or-443-to-kestrel)

Both products are from microsoft.

Comment: Keep your container listening on port `8080`, and instead set the `targetPort` ingress option to `8080`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/ingress-how-to

Comment: @Matthew, thanks, you are completely right. I was misled by the HealthCheck probes of Azure Container Apps. In previous .NET versions I did not have to specify any probes. Now it looks like I have to specify the HealthCheck probes and set the ports to 8080.

Comment: Just setting the `targetPort` in Ingress worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET 8 linux containers are not running under user "root" anymore. And because port 80 is a [Privileged port](https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html), you cannot make Kestrel listen on port 80.

You can set the TargetPort ingress option to 8080. If you are using HealthCheck probes of Azure Container Apps, you also have to set these ports to 8080.